# More output than desired in an array of string

Tags: c

I am trying to solve a problem. You can ignore the problem in the code. My doubt is that if I am taking the value of t as 2, still the array outputs 3 strings although I am running the loop only t times for output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){
  int t;
  int i;
  int j;
  int n;
  int c;
  int temp;
  char result[30][3];
  int flag;
  scanf("%d", &t);
  for(i = 0; i < t; i++){
    flag = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%d", &c);
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
      scanf("%d", &temp);
      if(c > temp){
      c = c - temp;
    } else{
      flag = 1;
    }
    }
    if(flag == 0){
      strcpy(result[i], "Yes");
    } else{
      strcpy(result[i], "No");
    }
  }

  for(i = 0; i < t; i++){
    printf("%s", result[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to declare `char result[30][4]` to allow room for the trailing null in `"Yes"`

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: I would be happy to know if there is a way to reduce the time complexity of this code in any way? @bar

Comment: For that we need to know what the problem is, which you said is not important.

Comment: regarding; `strcpy(result[i], "Yes");`  This takes 4 characters, 3 for the word 'Yes' and 1 for the terminating NUL character

Answer (score 1):

Add a `\n` when you `printf` a `result[i]`, then you'll find that you actually output 2 strings. For example， if you first `strcpy(result[0], "Yes")` and then `strcpy(result[0], "No")`, you'll get the outputs like this:

> YesNo
>
> No

In fact, the storage of `result` is as follows:

> result[0]: ['Y']['e']['s']
>
> result[1]: ['N']['o']['\0']

You get "YesNo" when you output `result[0]`, since a two-dimensional array is stored contiguously in the memory and a string ends with `\0`.

As another example, if you `strcpy(result[0], "Hello")`, then when you output `result[0]`, you'll get

> Hello

and when you output `result[1]`, you'll get

> lo

Since the storage in `result` is as follows:

> result[0]: ['H']['e']['l']
>
> result[1]: ['l']['o']['\0']